# Struts 2 "if" tag

Tags: struts2, struts

In my application, I use Struts 2.

In one page, I want to use the Struts 2 `<s:if>` tag, but can't get it to work.

In the action, I expose a "person" entity to the view.

Then in the page, I want to compare the current date with the person's birthday.

I tried this:

```
<s:if test="person.birthday > new java.util.Date()">xxxx</s:if>
```

But it does not work.

How to fix it?

Comment: what is the data-type of `person.brithday`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are using `Date` as a data type for `person.brithday`.You can do it as follows way

> If you can change/Modify your action add new java.util.Date() to action as a new field.

Additionally using `java.util.Date()` is not good practice at all since most of its method are deprecated so i suggest you to use `java.util.Calendar` which is more flexible.

You can use `Date.equals(), Date.before() and Date.after()` to compare 2 dates.All you need to do something as follows

```
<s:if test="%{person.brithday.before(currentdate)}">
    inside If block
 </s:if>
 <s:else>
    else block
</s:else>
```

Where i am assuming that `currentDate` is being set in your Action class, but if you want to change it to use it only in jsp page can change it.

Comment: IMO if the current date isn't used elsewhere on the page, it'd be better to just set an "isBirthday" flag in the action and expose that; easier to test, and keeps the calculation out of the view.