# Date comparision in struts2 using OGNL

Tags: struts2, ognl

enter code hereIn my JSP I have display a hyperlink depending upon the date field if it falls between certain range. I am using struts 2 and ONGL

```
<s:set name="cDate" value="accDate"/>
<s:if test="%{#cDate gt '4/4/11' &&  #cDate gt  '4/4/12}">                                                           
<td class="viewCellLast"><s:url id="editURL" action="editActivities">
<s:param name="id" value="%{id}"></s:param>
 </s:url> <s:a href="%{editURL}" onclick="return nanCompany();" >Edit</s:a></td>
 </s:if>
```

its failing, can anybody suggest the me how this can achieved.

thanks
smitha.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8687084/584420 - See Umesh's answer

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved; I missed # in front fsDate:

```xml
<s:set name="fsDate" value="finStartDate"/>
       <s:if test="%{#acDate.before(#fsDate}">
      <td class="viewCellLast"><s:url id="editURL" action="editActivities">
      <s:param name="id" value="%{id}"></s:param>
  </s:url> <s:a href="%{editURL}" >Edit</s:a> </td>
</s:if>
```